# Send button not firing any action

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a page for multiple users to chat with each other. So i chanced upon this great tutorial which has given me what i wanted. Here's the link reference: [Multi User Chat Room Using ASP NET 2.0 and AJAX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17813/Multi-User-Chat-Room-Using-ASP-NET-2-0-and-AJAX)

However, the Send button was not firing any action and messages were not posted in the textbox as shown in the tutorial. Every other details worked fine. I do not really know where is the problem as when i debug, no error was shown.

Here's the Chat.aspx page:

```
<div  onunload="Leave()">
    <input id="hdnRoomID" type="hidden" name="hdnRoomID" runat="server"/>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True" EnablePageMethods="True">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="scripts.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="80%">
               <asp:textbox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" id="txt" style="Width: 690px; HEIGHT: 260px" rows="16" Columns="79" ></asp:textbox>
                <br />
               <asp:TextBox id="txtMsg" Width="400" Runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               <input id="btn" onclick="button_clicked()" type="button" value="SEND" />
            </td>
            <td width="20%" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                Room Members <br />                   
               <asp:ListBox runat="server" Width="100" ID="lstMembers" Enabled="false" Height="249px"></asp:ListBox>                  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The onclick send button was fired here in a scripts.js:

```
function button_clicked() {
    PageMethods.SendMessage($get("txtMsg").value, $get("hdnRoomID").value, UpdateMessages, errorCallback);
    $get("txtMsg").value = "";
    $get("txt").scrollIntoView("true");
}

function clickButton(e, buttonid) {
    var bt = document.getElementById(buttonid);
    if (typeof bt == 'object') {
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape") > (-1)) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                bt.click();
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet Explorer") > (-1)) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                bt.click();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my Chat's aspx.cs code with [WebMethods] included:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["custName"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("ChatRoom.aspx");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["rid"]))
        Response.Redirect("ChatRoom.aspx");

    txtMsg.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(event,'btn')");
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        hdnRoomID.Value = Request.QueryString["rid"];
        ChatRoom room = ChatEngine.GetRoom(hdnRoomID.Value);
        string prevMsgs = room.JoinRoom(Session["custName"].ToString(), Session["custName"].ToString());
        txt.Text = prevMsgs;
        foreach (string s in room.GetRoomUsersNames())
        {
            lstMembers.Items.Add(new ListItem(s, s));
        }

    }


}


#region Script Callback functions

/// <summary>
/// This function is called from the client script 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="msg"></param>
/// <param name="roomID"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[WebMethod]
static public string SendMessage(string msg, string roomID)
{
    try
    {
        ChatRoom room = ChatEngine.GetRoom(roomID);
        string res = "";
        if (room != null)
        {
            res = room.SendMessage(msg, HttpContext.Current.Session["custName"].ToString());
        }
        return res;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return "";
}


/// <summary>
/// This function is called peridically called from the user to update the messages
/// </summary>
/// <param name="otherUserID"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[WebMethod]
static public string UpdateUser(string roomID)
{
    try
    {
        ChatRoom room = ChatEngine.GetRoom(roomID);
        if (room != null)
        {
            string res = "";
            if (room != null)
            {
                res = room.UpdateUser(HttpContext.Current.Session["custName"].ToString());
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return "";
}


/// <summary>
/// This function is called from the client when the user is about to leave the room
/// </summary>
/// <param name="otherUser"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[WebMethod]
static public string LeaveRoom(string roomID)
{
    try
    {
        ChatRoom room = ChatEngine.GetRoom(roomID);
        if (room != null)
            room.LeaveRoom(HttpContext.Current.Session["custName"].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return "";
}


/// <summary>
/// Returns a comma separated string containing the names of the users currently online
/// </summary>
/// <param name="roomID"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[WebMethod]
static public string UpdateRoomMembers(string roomID)
{
    try
    {
        ChatRoom room = ChatEngine.GetRoom(roomID);
        if (room != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> users = room.GetRoomUsersNames();
            string res = "";

            foreach (string s in users)
            {
                res += s + ",";
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return "";
}
#endregion
```

}

Comment: ScriptManager must be into a form! Did you checked it? and önunload from the div, did you noticed that ö not o? Another thing, the link that you provide, theres no link there!

Comment: Usually when buttons do nothing, it's because there is some sort of validation preventing the postback. To test this, try setting `CausesValidation="false"` on the button.

Comment: Looks like theres no form! No form, no data for post!

Comment: @Fals: He could be using a master page or something, or possibly only posted the relevant code. Also, even without a form I believe the button would still attempt to trigger some sort of action. From what I understood of the question, the button is completely unresponsive.

Comment: Yes, I did this using a masterpage and sorry for not having the link. I have just edited to make the link appear.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: I have added the CausesValidation="false" on the button but still, the button does not fire any action to post messages on the multi-lined textbox.

Comment: I notice that the original developer who posted the tutorial uses    <body onunload="Leave()"> whereas i used <div  onunload="Leave()">. Is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: @kelly Did you debugged the request/response using Feddler or Chrome page inspector? We need more information to help you out! Wheres the aspx page? Did you marked the method that you are calling as WebMethod?

Comment: I have added my aspx.cs webmethod codes for your reference.